# Calculating $ \int x^2(x+20)^{2020} dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to calculate the integral
$$
\int x^2(x+20)^{2020} dx
$$
The only thing that comes to my mind is to use the binomial expansion, but this is definitely not the way that is implied. Any suggestions?

Comment: try to use a change of variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Substitute $x+20=t$ and compute.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply substitute $u=x+20$, $du=dx$. Then,
$$\int x^2(x+20)^{2020}dx=\int (u-20)^2 u^{2020}du\\=\int u^{2022}-40u^{2021}+400u^{2020}du=\dfrac{u^{2023}}{2023}-\dfrac{20u^{2022}}{1011}+\dfrac{400u^{2021}}{2021}+C\\=\dfrac{(x+20)^{2023}}{2023}-\dfrac{20(x+20)^{2022}}{1011}+\dfrac{400(x+20)^{2021}}{2021}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x+20=t$ then
$$I=\int x^2(x+20)^{2000} dx=\int (t-20)^2~t^{2000}~dt= \int (t^{2002}-40 t^{2001}+400 t^{2000})$$ 
$$=\left(\frac{(x+20)^{2003}}{2003}-40\frac{(x+20)^{2002}}{2002}+400\frac{(x+20)^{2001}}{2001}+C\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, edited now.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x^2(x+20)^{2020}dx &= \int (x^2 + 40x + 400)(x+20)^{2020}dx  \\
 &= \int (x^2 + 40x + 400)(x+20)^{2020}dx - \int (40x + 400)(x+20)^{2020}dx  \\
 &= \int (x+20)^2(x+20)^{2020}dx - 40\int (x + 10)(x+20)^{2020}dx \\
 &= \int (x+20)^{2022}dx - 40\int (x + 10 + 10)(x+20)^{2020}dx + 40\int 10(x+20)^{2020}dx  \\
 &= \int (x+20)^{2022}dx - 40\int (x+20)^{2021}dx + 400\int (x+20)^{2020}dx  \\
 &= \int (x+20)^{2022}d(x+20) - 40\int (x+20)^{2021}d(x+20) + 400\int (x+20)^{2020}d(x+20)  \\
 &= \frac{(x+20)^{2023}}{2023} - 40\frac{(x+20)^{2022}}{2022} + 400\frac{(x+20)^{2021}}{2021} + C 
\end{aligned}
$$